# jquery obout grid ie10 not load

Tags: ajax, jqgrid, internet-explorer-10, obout

I am using obout jquery grid, it working fine in ie9 and ie10 in compatible view. but other css styles and validation not working in previous ie10 browsers. Any suggestion how to overcome this issue?

Comment: And where is the code which you use or at least the URL to your demo? Which version of jQuery, jQuery UI and jqGrid you use? I believe that your code works wrong in IE10, but you should understand that one can't find the error in your code if one don't see it.

Comment: Actually, the code is blinded, its ready made product from obout. And I did some project to show the issue example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100549308/obout_Grid_Example.zip .And you can visit <http://www.obout.com/grid/> to see that. Thank for helping.

Comment: Moreover, many jguery grids also have same issue. for example <http://flexigrid.info/> . if you open the page in compatibility view it works fine.

Comment: `http://www.obout.com/grid/` uses **another grid**. It has no relation with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) which you used as the Tag of your question. `flexigrid` is one more grid which is of cause also not jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, actually its not a bug but the download accelerator program conflict with ie 10. so after uninstalling it everything works as required.